# PHP can't use `class` anymore (just not working)

Tags: php, class, include

Currently I am developing something with PHP and yesterday everything worked fine. Today nothing is working and I figured out it is because `class` doesn't work anymore. My code looks like this:

```
<?php
    // Code
    echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() . "\n";
    echo("1 \n");
    include_once 'test.php';
    echo("2 \n");
    //Code
?>
```

My `test.php` looks like this (just for testing):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo("Start \n");

class test
{
    echo("IN CLASS");
}

echo("End \n");
?>
```

My output looks like:

> Current PHP version: 5.5.30-1~dotdeb+7.1
>
> 1
>
> (empty line)

If I remove the `class` from `test.php` it works:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo("Start \n");

// class test
// {
//     echo("IN CLASS");
// }

echo("End \n");
?>
```

My output looks like:

> Current PHP version: 5.5.30-1~dotdeb+7.1
>
> 1
>
> Start
>
> End
>
> 2
>
> (empty line)

Does anybody know what is going on? I have no idea why I can't use `class` anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [PHP `class`](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php) is a collection of variables (`var`) and functions (`function`) working with these variables, and is defined using the following syntax:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    var $myVar;

    function myFunction() {
        // ...
    }
}
?>
```

Your `class` definition does not follow this rule, since `echo` is unexpected!